# How do I reduce the run time of this C++ code?

Tags: c++, performance, runtime, coding-efficiency

The task is to reduce the runtime of the below program. We have an array A of n elements and we take input of q queries in the form of two integers both separated by a space. We need to find the number of pairs (x,y) such that x<y and product of the x<sup>th</sup> and y<sup>th</sup> element of the array is even.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n,q; //n is the size of array arr and q is the number of queries asked
    cin>>n>>q;
    int arr[n];
    int b,a,count=0;
    //Initialization of array elements
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    //Taking q queries with two integers such that a<=x<=b and a<=y<=b. We need to find pairs (x,y) such that x<y and (arr[x-1]*arr[y-1]) is even.
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        cin>>a>>b;
        for(int x=a;x<=b;x++){
            for (int y=a;y<=b;y++){
                if ((x<y)&&((arr[x-1]*arr[y-1])%2==0)) count++;  //(x,y) is the required pair
            }
        }
        cout<<count<<endl;
        count=0;
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have a program in one language, then please don't add other unrelated language tags to your question.

Comment: And technically you don't have a valid C++ program either, as C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: The innermost loop should be `for (int y = x+1; y<=b;y++)` I think.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: hint : a product of 2 integers is even if at least 1 of the 2 integers is even. So, knowing how many even integers are between the given indexes should allow you to calculate the desired result.

Comment: @KenY-N Only if the code truly works. They have a pretty strict policy against non-working code.

Comment: I would reword the question to "1) this is my assignment..., 2) here's my attempt at solving it..., 3) my solution is too slow. How to make it faster?"

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and your valuable time. I am new to programming as well as StackOverflow. I'll keep in mind all your suggestions in the future.